# Ajax calls are not working only in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I have implemented the cart/jquery ajax tutorial from this [codeigniter cart and jquery from nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-build-a-shopping-cart-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/)

It works wonderful in all browsers except IE..I'm thinking it has to do with a css selector that maybe earlier versions of IE doesnt support. What it doesn't do is ajaxify the adding to the cart like it is suppose to. I know the post is successful but the .get and loading of that returned data in to div isn't. I know the post is working because if you hit the update cart button it will show all the added items that ajax should of added and updated the list without  a page reload.

Here is my JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    /*place jQuery actions here*/ 
    var link = "";


    $("ul.products form").submit(function() {
        // Get the product ID and the quantity 
        var id = $(this).find('input[name=product_id]').val();
        var qty = $(this).find('input[name=quantity]').val();

         $.post(link + "cart/add_cart_item", { product_id: id, quantity: qty, ajax: '1' },
            function(data){

            if(data == 'true'){

                $.get(link + "cart/show_cart", function(cart){
                    $("#cart_content").html(cart);
                });

            }else{
                alert("Product does not exist");
            }   

         }); 

        return false;
    });

    $(".empty").live("click", function(){
        $.get(link + "cart/empty_cart", function(){
            $.get(link + "cart/show_cart", function(cart){
                $("#cart_content").html(cart);
            });
        });

        return false;
    });




});
```

Here is the processing php for the ajax calls::

```
<?php

class Cart extends MX_Controller { // Our Cart class extends the  hmvc (MX)Controller class

 function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); // We define the the Controller class is the parent. 
        $this->load->model('cart_model'); // Load our cart model for our entire class
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['products'] = $this->cart_model->retrieve_products(); // Retrieve an array with all products

        $data['content'] = 'cart/cart/products'; // Select view to display
        $this->load->view('index', $data); // Display the page
    }

    function add_cart_item(){

        if($this->cart_model->validate_add_cart_item() == TRUE){

            // Check if user has javascript enabled
            if($this->input->post('ajax') != '1'){
                redirect('cart'); // If javascript is not enabled, reload the page with new data
            }else{
                echo 'true'; // If javascript is enabled, return true, so the cart gets updated
            }
        }

    }

    function update_cart(){
        $this->cart_model->validate_update_cart();
        redirect('cart');
    }

    function show_cart(){
        $this->load->view('cart/cart/cart.php');
    }

    function empty_cart(){
        $this->cart->destroy();
        redirect('cart');
    }
    function checkout(){
    $numitems=$this->cart->total_items();

    if($numitems>1){
    //more then 1 item
    $this->load->library('Paypal_Lib');
    $multiproductarray=$this->cart->contents();
    //echo var_dump($multiproductarray); return;
    $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'business', $this->config->item( 'paypal_email' ));
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'return', site_url( 'paypal/success' ) );
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'cancel_return', site_url( 'paypal/cancel' ) );
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'notify_url', site_url( 'paypal/ipn' ) ); // <-- IPN url
            $this->paypal_lib->multi_items('true');
            $i=1; // keeps track for _number
            foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items){
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'item_name_'.$i, $items['name'] );
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'item_number_'.$i, $items['id'] );
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'amount_'.$i, $items['price'] );
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'quantity_'.$i, $items['qty'] );
        //  $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'quantity_'.$i, '10' );
            $i++;
            }
            redirect( $this->paypal_lib->paypal_get_request_link() );//this sends to paypal


    }else{
    //1 item
        $this->load->library( 'Paypal_Lib' );
        //$singleproductarray=$this->cart->contents();
        //echo var_dump($singleproductarray); return;
        //echo $singleproductarray['name'].$singleproductarray['id'].$singleproductarray['price']; return;
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'business', $this->config->item( 'paypal_email' ));
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'return', site_url( 'paypal/success' ) );
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'cancel_return', site_url( 'paypal/cancel' ) );
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'notify_url', site_url( 'paypal/ipn' ) ); // <-- IPN url
            $this->paypal_lib->multi_items('false');
            //$this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'item_name', $singleproductarray['name'] );
        //  /$this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'item_number', $singleproductarray['id'] );
            //$this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'amount', $singleproductarray['price'] );
                foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items){
                    $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'item_name', $items['name'] );
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'item_number', $items['id'] );
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'amount', $items['price'] );
                    $this->paypal_lib->add_field( 'quantity', $items['qty'] );

            }
            redirect( $this->paypal_lib->paypal_get_request_link() );//this sends to paypal

    }

    }
}

/* End of file cart.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/cart.php */




<?php 

class Cart_model extends CI_Model {

    // Function to retrieve an array with all product information
    function retrieve_products(){
        $query = $this->db->get('products');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    // Updated the shopping cart
    function validate_update_cart(){

        // Get the total number of items in cart
        $total = $this->cart->total_items();

        // Retrieve the posted information
        $item = $this->input->post('rowid');
        $qty = $this->input->post('qty');

        // Cycle true all items and update them
        for($i=0;$i < $total;$i++)
        {
            // Create an array with the products rowid's and quantities. 
            $data = array(
               'rowid' => $item[$i],
               'qty'   => $qty[$i]
            );

            // Update the cart with the new information
            $this->cart->update($data);
        }

    }

    // Add an item to the cart
    function validate_add_cart_item(){

        $id = $this->input->post('product_id'); // Assign posted product_id to $id
        $cty = $this->input->post('quantity'); // Assign posted quantity to $cty

        $this->db->where('id', $id); // Select where id matches the posted id
        $query = $this->db->get('products', 1); // Select the products where a match is found and limit the query by 1

        // Check if a row has been found
        if($query->num_rows > 0){

            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'id'      => $id,
                    'qty'     => $cty,
                    'price'   => $row->price,
                    'name'    => $row->name
                );

                $this->cart->insert($data); 

                return TRUE;
            }

        // Nothing found! Return FALSE! 
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Needed?
    //function cart_content(){
    //  return $this->cart->total();
    //}

}


/* End of file cart_model.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/cart_model.php */
```

Whats happening is after the first item is loaded to the cart (through ajax, and is successful) it will continue to add items but the ajax won't update the ul list items on the screen unless I manually press Update Cart button. Problem only exists in IE

thank you!

Comment: ill accept answers when i receive them

Comment: You'll receive answers when you show basic debugging effort. It takes 10 seconds to stick couple of `alert()` around to figure out if your code is being called. And it takes another minute to see if your code works outside of the complex ajax scope. You've done neither, but you expect answers.

Comment: not near pc ..maybe not for this question but normally I post all code. don't see how alerts will help or where to put them as this works in all other browsers. not sure what isn't ok for ie..ill update tomm its late here

Comment: To be sure you first need to figure out what is "it". That is done by narrowing issue down to a specific line. But if you wanna just sit around and wait for someone to look at a pile of code and tell what is wrong with it, that is fine to.

Comment: How can I narrow it down when no error pops up at all it just doesn't work in some versions of IE. It is morning now (was late night when i posted originally) so I'm going to try suggestions then I'll report back. Your suggestion doesn't help. $("#cart_content").html(cart); does work

Comment: If there were a firebug for IE it would be 100% easier but that part why IE sucks

Comment: What version of IE???? (also, @CI_Guy - there is Firebug Lite, which can run on IE. doesn't do everything the full Firebug does, but can be helpful)

Comment: ie 7/8..I'll look into it and see if it can help me

Comment: @CI_Guy Well then there is only two possibilities. Either that line is being called and does work and you imagining your problem, or your debug effort is too shallow.

Answer (score 1):

what are you echo from server

is it `echo true ;` then you should use `if(data == true)`

is it  `echo 'true' ;` then you should use `if(data == 'true')`

`echo 1;` then you should use `if($.trim(data) == 1)`

try to use `$.trim(data)` instead of `data`

hope this may be helpful .